# Why is there an additional column created using xtab that doesn't sum the number across all other columns?

Tags: r, xtabs

I'm trying to decipher another person's script, so this is more of unfamiliarity with xtabs than anything. I've read the documentation but I still don't understand why using xtabs gives me an additional row with numbers that don't add up across the other columns? Help will be greatly appreciated!

Code

```
data <- structure(list(Date = c("2-Nov-20", "2-Nov-20", "2-Nov-20", "2-Nov-20", 
"2-Nov-20", "2-Nov-20"), Cycle = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Route = c("T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1"), Waypoint = c("FQ1120", "FQ1121", 
"FQ1122", "FQ1123", "FQ1127", "FQ1125"), Latitude = c("1.326983012", 
"1.327218041", "1.327946009", "1.328284973", "1.329542007", "1.329018977"
), Longitude = c("103.659741", "103.659496", "103.659467", "103.65963", 
"103.660734", "103.659631"), Sampling.point = c("T01_01", "T01_01", 
"T01_01", "T01_02", "T01_20", "T01_02"), Latitude.1 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Longitude.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Time..24h. = c("1947", 
"1948", "1950", "1952", "2003", "1957"), Common.name = c("Wild pig", 
"Red junglefowl", "Changeable lizard", "Savanna nightjar", "Changeable lizard", 
"Yellow-vented bulbul"), Taxon = c("Mammal", "Bird", "Reptile", 
"Bird", "Reptile", "Bird"), Scientific.name = c("Sus scrofa", 
"Gallus gallus", "Calotes versicolor", "Caprimulgus affinis", 
"Calotes versicolor", "Pycnonotus goiavier"), Global.status..IUCN.CITES. = c("Least Concern", 
"Least Concern", "Not Assessed", "Least Concern", "Not Assessed", 
"Least Concern"), Local.status..Davison.et.al...2008..Jain.et.al...2018.for.butterflies..Soh.et.al...2019.for.odonates. = c("Not Assessed", 
"Endangered", "Not Assessed", "Not Assessed", "Not Assessed", 
"Not Assessed"), Quantity = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L), Observation.type..seen.heard.caught.scat.other.signs. = c("Seen", 
"Seen", "Seen", "Heard", "Seen", "Seen"), Photo.no. = c("", "", 
"", "", "", ""), Survey.method..targeted.incidental.point.count.trapping. = c("Incidental", 
"Incidental", "Targeted", "Targeted", "Targeted", "Targeted"), 
    Remarks = c("", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")

data$Quantity <- as.numeric(data$Quantity) #check quantity doesn't have text or >n

data.matrix <- xtabs(Quantity~Scientific.name+Sampling.point, data=data)
```

This generates a table with rownames=scientific name; colnames=sampling.point with Quantity filling each grid/cell. But an additional column is also generated---I'm not sure what that is supposed to be cos it doesn't sum across the qty from all the sampling_points!

Is this more an issue with my code? If anyone can explain what that new column is that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which additional column are you talking about?

Comment: Some of those column names make it appear that there is a problem with data import (`Local.status..Davison.et.al...2008..Jain.et.al...2018.for.butterflies..Soh.et.al...2019.for.odonates.` looks like it has data embedded in that column name). Given the schema of the data, I would expect a name like `Local.status` or such. This suggests there might be other things wrong with your data (perhaps even that we do not see here), which can produce anomalies with console output from other tools.

Comment: Is "T01_20" in row 5 just a typo for "T01_02"? The sum of the frequencies `sum(data.matrix)` and `sum(data$Quantity)` are both 14 as would be expected.